Repartitioning Centos Stream 9 Server with RAID 1
The server in question is a server that I work on used primarily as a simulation server. It runs on CentOS 8 stream (which I did not initially set up) and I believe it has been partitioned poorly. The hardware is 2 M.2 SSDs which were which were intended to be in RAID 1. I will include a screenshot of lsblk (below) to illustrate the current partitioning.

It appears to me that only the /home directory is being used in raid 1, all the other directories are stored on only 1 of the 2 drives (nvme1n1). One of the main issues this is causing is that nvme1n1p5 mounted on / is only 70 gigabytes and it has been getting filled up very quickly, I have had to clear data from it multiple times to keep the server running. I will include a screenshot of df -h (below), and, as you can see, nvme1n1p4 is already 60% full even after I cleared it this morning.

What would be the best way to go about doing this repartition? I was thinking I could move all the data from nvme1n1 to a single partition on nvme0n1 mounted to /, then set up RAID 1 with that / directory on both SSDs. Am I missing anything? Do I need to set up separate partitions for /boot or anything? I'm also unfamiliar with which commands would be best to do these operations with.

"Am I missing anything" questions aren't really what we do here. We do specific answers to practical and specific questions. If something is actually broken, tell us what is broken, the efforts you've made to fix it, and give as much detail as you can. I would guess there's already pretty good documentation online about repartitioning drives in CentOS, but I'd also recommend that you take a full system image backup (best safety there it) and that you consider whether what you are trying to do is the best solution to the problem(s) you are facing.
